# Laravel Eloquent - For loop inside seeder file is behaving in a strange way

Tags: laravel

I have two models, article and project. project can have many related articles and an article can belong to one project or it may not. I have two seeder projectseeder and articleseeder. article seeder is called first and runs fine and then I try to run a for loop inside project seeder to associate some random articles, the result is only one article is added to the collection. Strangely The article which is added  has the same id as project i.e. if project id is 1 then the associated article id is also 1. I am out of my wits as to why the for loop inside the project seeder is not working as expected.

```
   class Article extends Model{
    //An Article can only belong to one project or it could be independent of project
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project', 'id');
    }
```

```
class Project extends Model
{

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article', 'id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And my factory and seeders

```
$factory->define(Article::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'         => $faker->sentence(rand(1,2)),
        'short_text'    => $faker->sentence(rand(3,5)),
        'content'       => $faker->paragraph(10),
        'is_featured'   => $faker->randomElement(['Y','N']),
        'posted_by'     =>'John Smith'

    ];
});
```

```
class ProjectTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        Eloquent::unguard();

        //select  random articles for project
        factory(App\Models\Project::class, 10)->create()
            ->each(function($project){
                //associate 3 random article with this project
                for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) {
                    $project->articles->add(Article::find(rand(1,50))->get());
                }//end for
        }//end each function
        );


        Eloquent::reguard();

    }
}
```

I die dump the relation but I get only one instance of article. Please help me find out what i am doing wrong! thanks in advance for your kind help.

UPDATE #1:
These are the migration files for the models

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('short_text'); // Mandetory first 150 chars of content
            $table->text('content');
            $table->char('is_featured'); // Y for N for No
            $table->string('posted_by'); // Auth user
        });
```

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->text('title');
        });
```

Update #2:

Thank you so much for the answer. I am amazed that you actually created a whole project to answer my question!!! That's so nice of you and I really appreciate your spirit. Your solution works like a charm.

I don't know if it would be asking too much but this is the last help I'd ask for.
All 10 projects have the same related articles i.e. from article 0 to 5. I'd want to have random articles chosen instead of all project having same articles.

UPDATE#3
I have figured out a different approach and changed the factory methods

```
    $factory->define(Article::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'         => $faker->sentence(rand(1,2)),
        'short_text'    => $faker->sentence(rand(3,5)),
        'content'       => $faker->paragraph(10),
        'is_featured'   => $faker->randomElement(['Y','N']),
        'posted_by'     =>'John Smith',
        'project_id'    =>$faker->randomElement([null,rand(1,10)]),
    ];
});
```

Now articles either have nulls or random ids of project as project id and articles are now automatically related to the projects. Nonetheless thanks a bunch for your valuable time. Have a great day.

Comment: What colums do you have on each of the two tables? Most relevant are key and foreign key columns.

Answer (score 0):

First time posting an answer. :)

Your articles() relationship is using the id column from both tables to get the articles. This will cause you to only retrieve one article. If you add a 'projects_id' column to your articles table and set that column to the id of the project, and then modify your relationship to use that column, you will be able to get multiple articles.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:
Adding ->nullable() to the migration column allows you to leave it null or set it to a specific project.

Migration:

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('projects_id')->nullable(); 
            // Add column that specifies what project this belongs to
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('short_text'); // Mandetory first 150 chars of content
            $table->text('content');
            $table->char('is_featured'); // Y for N for No
            $table->string('posted_by'); // Auth user
        });
```

Relationship:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article', 'projects_id', 'id');
    // Use the projects_id we just added to get all 
    // articles for that project
}
```

I would recommend reading through the Laravel documentation, specifically migrations and relationships.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

UPDATE #2:

Article Migration: https://pastebin.com/QaDUzG9x

Project Migration: https://pastebin.com/4i9Bg5vQ

Article & Project Model: https://pastebin.com/8GWmcx7U

Seeder: https://pastebin.com/MDi2nW5N

Article & Project Factory: https://pastebin.com/BUFfP7iv

Download project: http://www.mediafire.com/file/wv5188frvd0k9m0/devtest.zip/file

Using `php artisan tinker` and `App\Project::first()->articles` I was able to get the first Project in the database along with all of its articles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Articles can be independent of project. They may or may not belong to a project. As such i cannot use a project id in the article table as it may remain null.

Comment: You are able to make the projects_id null by adding ->nullable() to the migration. That will allow you leave them null or set them to the specific project. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Johnny I hope this helped, if you have any more questions feel free to ask! Using a projects_id column and the nullable() attribute on your column should fit your needs by allowing you to get multiple articles for one project **OR** having stand alone articles that don't belong to a project.

Comment: Hi ImJT, thanks again, seeding is working now after changing the foreign key but this time no article is being added to the collection!

Comment: When I get a chance today, I'll go ahead and write something on the lines of what you're looking for and modify my answer with it. Are your articles being given a project id now? Without the project id, you will not receive any related articles for the project.

Comment: Thats the irony here. First the articles r seeded but in the article factory  i cant give value to project id since its still not related to a project.  Hence all project id col are null but then i try to seed project and add articles to project which doesnt work because project id is null!! Is there a way to insert project id to the related articles column from within the project factory or project seeder file ??

Comment: Btw thanks for your quick response and your admirable attitude for helping people in need. These days its hard for us to spare our time from our busy schedule.

Comment: @Johnny I went ahead and update my answer with some pastebin links that have snippets of code and a mediafire link that will give you the entire project. I really hope this helps. Each project is given 6 articles, which I was able to get them all using the relationship.